# code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack, but the module is visible and the file path is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm having an issue with running an app on localhost with `npm start notes`.
I keep getting this error

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/shebang-command/index.js',
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/util/readShebang.js',
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/parse.js',
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js',
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/react-dev-utils/crossSpawn.js',
    '/Users/macintoshi/VS Code/codes/notes.c/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js'
  ]
}
```

But the paths are all correct and the modules exist there.

I'm using Node.js version 16.14.2. and npm version 8.5.0

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "json-server -p3001 --watch db.json"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "json-server": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of module system do you use ESM or common CJS? If you use ESM, add `"type":"module" ` to `package.json`